# How can I make a chart that automatically adds info with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a tracker of stuff I do every day, like the amount of water I drink, how much I exercise, read, whatever, and store that info in two sheets, one with 365-day info and one with all the days

I also want to have an excel graph that I can quickly take a look at (meaning I don't want to have to set it up every time I want to see it). Doing that for the 365 days thing should be easy by just setting a locked range of 365 cells, but in any case it would only look pretty once I've been using it for some months.

This [webpage](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel-tips/how-to-make-charts-auto-update/1/) shows exactly how to do it when you input the info manually, but I'm using openpyxl to input the info for me via a telegram bot. I tried doing that then adding a value right below the table with code and it doesn't work.

My theory is that once you call that cell it gets emptied of any kind of attributes (format) it might have before setting a value.

Example: If you make the cells (B2:D4) have all borders and then execute `ws['C3'] = 5`, it will remove the borders of that cell because you didn't explicitly told Excel to "keep them" (or, more accurate, set them again)

The example can be fixed using `openpyxl.styles`, but how do I make excel "check", or add new values to the existing table? I assume that if I get them to join the table, they will be added to the graph too.

This is a personal project, not an assignment or anything, so if there's another way to do the same, I'm okay with that.

Edit: I've been playing with `dir(ws.tables['Table1'])` and found an (attribute?) called `insertRow`, but I can't find anything at all that explains what it does, only how it works (Boolean that allows `None`). I tried manually changing it from None to True and then trying again, but when I opened the file it said it needed to be repaired, and when repaired it added the value but didn't make it join the table...

Comment: **My theory is that once you call that cell it gets emptied of any kind of attributes (format) it might have before setting a value.Example: If you make the cells (B2:D4) have all borders and then execute ws['C3'] = 5, it will remove the borders of that cell because you didn't explicitly told Excel to "keep them" (or, more accurate, set them again)** I disagree. Also openpyxl is not interacting with Excel.

Comment: Is there a code example of what you are attempting?

Comment: @moken I haven't done much for now, but you can find the code [here](https://pastebin.com/Kr8m9cTM)
The `new_day()` function should do more than that but well, it should basically add a day to both sheets and leave some values (run should be yesterday +1, water should be 0...)

Comment: @moken I'm not sure, I'm just a beginner in programming :) but it is true the borders thing, if you have one cell with borders and do `ws.[cell]` = 5, that cell will have value 5 (stored as text) and no borders

Comment: With the border situation, you should check you have a late or the latest release of Openpyxl, now 3.1.0. If you do or it still happens after installing the latest release, you might want to raise an issue with the Devs.

Comment: @moken damn you're right, it doesn't happen now... Maybe it happened before because I was scrapping info from a borderless table in a website and it might have taken more info than just the value? No idea :(